# Is it normal to want to use an escrow service to hold a wedding venue deposit?

Tags: escrow, wedding

I'll keep it as concise as possible. My fiancee and I have been planning on a particular date at a venue, it's about 2500 miles away from where we currently live (she's from there originally). It's not so much the deposit (50%) that freaks me out, but the lack of organization their main contact has, for example, she put us down for the wrong date and put a soft reservation on the specific date we asked for.

That being said. Sending a check for $5000 across the country, to me, seems absolutely ludicrous, it would be nearly impossible to take them to small claims should they renege on the contract or go bankrupt. Being a web developer and seeing their website I can easily within 2 hours mock-up something of equivalent look and feel and start taking checks and credit cards if I wanted to. (Obviously I don't need to do this I have a good job)

Is this tacky or out of the norm for someone to insist on an third party (escrow) holding the deposit until all conditions have been met?

Comment: Have you visited the venue? it sounds like you haven't because you mention sending a check across the country, and you are wondering about the qualify of the website. Also is this just the venue or are they also the caterer?

Comment: The website example was just me explaining how easy it would be to fake a venue and take money from the unsuspecting. I'll be visiting this venue before signing anything and putting down 50%, once I know they're real then potentially put down 50%, but it being a year away I'd rather earn the interest on the $$ not them. It's obviously going to be up to my fiancee ultimately but its a perfect excuse to visit New Orleans anyway :)  Just my infosec background coming through in my personal life  o.O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider it normal for most venues to have easy-to-replicate websites and for many to have dodgy organisational ability.

The 50% deposit does seem unusually high however. For example, the deposit on the venue for my wedding was 10%, and that came with a contract spelling out the date and responsibilities of both parties.

As for the disorganisation, I would definitely factor this into the potential risk you are taking in booking them. 
A good contract means in the worst case, you can recoup the cost of the venue losses, but it's unlikely to recover deposits / payments to other providers and more importantly, **you don't really want anything to go wrong at your wedding.**

This is the reason most suppliers charge more for weddings. They're costing the extra effort to reduce the risk of ruining a wedding day

Answer (score 5):

I would say, yes this is out of the norm.  If you don't trust the vendor don't use the vendor...

Answer (score 0):

You're free to negotiate payment terms as you like, but from the point of view of the venue, you are asking to put a hole in their cash flow compared to standard operations.   They can decide whether your business is worth the deviation, so be prepared for a "no".

If you don't like the way they do business (standard contract terms, apparent organization, web presence, whatever) then find an alternative.